# jQuery UI Draggable with custom containment in a fixed parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to have a constrained draggable in a fixed parent.
When I scroll down the the containmet region moves together with the body and not with the fixed child. Is there a way to prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fzSjx/7/

Html:

```
 <div id="o">
     <div id="draggable">
         <p>drag me</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable(
    { containment: [ 0 ,0, 200, 200], 
      scroll: false }
);
```

Css:

```
#o {
    position: fixed;
}
body {
    height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/fzSjx/4/ ???

Comment: No. As I have written I want a fixed parent. new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzSjx/7/

Comment: So like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fzSjx/8/ ???

Comment: Not 100% what I was asking for, but enough for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `position: absolute` on `#o`. `position: fixed` will fix the position of the div in the viewport, `position: absolute` will fix the div relative to nearest relatively positioned parent.

### EDIT:

You have the wrong value for containment, set it to be contained by its parent like this

```
$( '#draggable' ).draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    scroll: false
});
```

Comment: No I want a fixed parent. I updated the fiddle so that it becomes clearer.

Comment: I simplified my case too much. I have a draggable object that is bigger than the window. So I used the solution to enter negative numbers in the containment field. Instead it is also possible to have a container that is bigger than has negative values in left and top.

Comment: Still it is strange, that a containment statement with numeric values does not work with a fixed parent.